# Background Images not working in Android, BB, Windows Phone

Tags: android, html, css, windows-phone-7, blackberry

My Background Images was not working in Android, BB, Windows Phone. I want Common Code that want to support all Android, BB, windows Phone.

And also the Image Must Be Stretch Automatically based on the screeen size

Can any one please help Me..with some good solution.

Thanks

Comment: All those devices shouldn't have any problem with background images as it's basic CSS. What is the image type? SVG won't work on Androids if you're using that. Post some code please.

Comment: image type is JPG..if i find means i'll Post

Comment: Ok. Can you post some code please? Also do they work on ANY device?

Comment: in CSS: 
#backgrndImg {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

In HTML :
<span id="backgrndImg">
              <img width="100%" height="100%" alt="Background" src="images/background.jpg"/>
           </span>

Comment: the above code is works in Windows and Android but you have disable the background-image in js->jquery.mobile-1.1.0 at line 328-334..

Comment: You're not using background images. You're using a regular img tag. See my answer for using background images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution :

```
.ui-body-a,
{
background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat; 
background-position:center center; 
background-attachment:scroll; 
background-size:100% 100%;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had this issue too and setting the background size sorted it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ok the problem is that you're not setting a background image. You're using a regular image. To use a background image on your element you can use the following CSS (just note the background line).

Make sure the path to your image is relative to the CSS file. Not the root. Change the repeating and positioning settings accordingly - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

```
    #backgrndImg { 
        height: 100%; 
        left: 0; 
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0; 
        width: 100%; 
        z-index: -1; 
        background: url('images/your_image.jpg') no-repeat left top;
   } 

    <div id="backgrndImg"></div >
```

Comment: i tried but the image is not displaying..

Comment: Is the path to the image 100% right? It has to be relative to the CSS file.

Comment: yes the path is right & the image is not stretching fully.. And what is best screen for all mobile phones..

Comment: Can you set a JSFiddle up with your code please?

Comment: can you please explain want is JSFiddle.

Comment: yes both HTML as well as CSS.

Comment: Yes. Put your HTML and CSS and send a link.

Comment: Put the HTML and CSS in JSFiddle and link to that.

Answer (score 1):

What's your code? Doing it as simple as this works for me on my Android (both default Internet browser and Chrome):

```
​body{
    background-image:url("myBgUrl");
}​
```

Comment: That's not possible to do in a cross-browser way if you don't 1) Use css3 (not cross-browser friendly) 2) Use image tags instead of the background attribrute.